# Question about a proof that addition from the left preserves the order of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, ordinals

I found the following proof that ordinal addition from the left preserves strict inequalities (see b)).

[image]
[image]

I am having trouble understanding the limit stage. The proof uses the inequality

$\gamma + \alpha < S(\gamma + \alpha) = \gamma + S(\alpha) \leq \sup(\gamma + \theta: \theta < \beta)$.

My thoughts are as follows:
The first inequality simply follows from the definition of the successor of a set and the equality  after that follows from the definition of addition of ordinals. The last inequality follows from the fact that $S(\alpha) < \beta$ such that $\gamma + S(\alpha)$ is an element of the set {$\gamma + \theta: \theta < \beta$}.

Is there any error in my line of argument? The fact that I don't need the induction hypothesis for the limit stage is generally a sign that something is wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean you don’t need the induction argument?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku There was a typo in my post. I meant that I haven't used the induction hypothesis at the limit stage. I have edited my post.

Comment: If my answer answer's your question please accept/upvote it, to remove it from the unanswered queue. If not, I would be happy to provide any clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\beta$ is a limit, then pretty much by definition of a limit, ordinal addition with a limit, for all $\gamma$ we have that: $\alpha<\beta\to \gamma +\alpha<\gamma +\beta$. So you do not need the induction hypothesis. I will add that not using the induction hypothesis is not exactly uncommon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you elaborate, please? So am I right, that the claim for limit ordinals simply follows from the fact that $\gamma + S(\alpha)$ is a member of the set {$\gamma + \theta: \theta < \beta$}? If so, why don't we simply use the same argument for $\alpha$? $\gamma + \alpha$ should also be an element of that set.

Comment: Yes. @DerivativesGuy What do you mean by same argument for $\alpha$?

Comment: What I mean is this: $\alpha < \beta$, so this should imply that $\gamma + \alpha$ is an element of {$\gamma + \theta: \theta < \beta$}, right? And then the $\gamma + \alpha \leq sup(\gamma + \theta: \theta < \beta)$ follows directly from this  without the need to look at $S(\alpha)$

Comment: Ah, never mind. This way we cannot prove that the inequality is strict.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Yes, that’s correct.